# scala println string with quotes

Tags: scala

If you print a string in the console you'll get it without quotes, like this

```
scala> "asd"
res21: String = asd
```

which is great, but I have certain list of case classes being printed which I want to copy to later paste somewhere. The issue is that it wont compile freshly copied because the `"` are missing

Is there an easy way to output strings with quotes in the console?

To further clarify, I want the following

```
scala> "asd"
res21: String = "asd"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ammonite does quotes. There's an issue for REPL https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8603

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `toString` in your case classes:

```
case class MyClass(a: String, b: String) {
  override def toString = s"MyClass(a = \"$a\", b = \"$b\")"
}
```

The `a =` and `b =` are for clarity only (you can remove them if you don't need them), but they won't affect the pasted code.

Comment: Unfortunately the above does not work. There is a bug, see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476
s"""MyClass(a = \"$a\", b = \"$b\")"""
will work

Answer (score 1):

You can try with an empty space after the string

```
scala> "asd "
res11: String = "asd "
```

Comment: string interpolation is not needed.

Comment: That's a nice trick though, I wasn't aware of it (I had to test it)! Doesn't work in IntelliJ spreadsheet, however, not sure if this is a peculiarity of the REPL.

Comment: Indeed, after another test, this seems to be working only in scala console (REPL).

Comment: nice trick indeed, although it doesn't work for strings inside case classes. Take the following: `case class C(s:String); println(C("asd "))`. It will print: `C(asd )`

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
val x = """"asd""""
```

This triple quote interpolation can be what you're looking for (then you add one more quote to do what you need to do).

Comment: This changes the value of the string, not how it is printed out. If you are ok with adding quotes to your string, you can also escape them: `val x = "\"asd\""`.

Comment: Its not that I want quotes in strings but rather that I want string that would otherwise print without quotes **with** them

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry. Misunderstood. You basically want to somehow override the `toString` method for the `String` type.